# Eclipse dynamic web project - static resources are not accessible

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I have a dynamic web project in eclipse,for some reason static resources are not accessible from the browser, project structure is:

```
- src
   - com
- Web root
   - javaScripts
   - CSS
   - WEB-INF
```

Project is deployed to tomcat in eclipse, and is working OK (spring loaded, db connections,jsp, controllers etc)
but i am unable to access static javaScripts,CSS resources from the browser,
in the deployment assembly i have the Web root defined as /

What am I missing?

Comment: your WEB-INF should be inside the root

Comment: WEB-INF is inside the root , sorry it was a typo thanks for pointing this out.